# Laravel Mix suddenly stopped compiling SCSS and writes empty files

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, sass, laravel-mix

Just a few days ago, everything within my mix compiled correctly, no matter whether js to js or scss to css. In the meanwhile I changed nothing in the scss files or anything with the mix or overall setup. However, I moved some of my project's jsb files within my Laravel project's resources/js folder and adjusted all respective includes accordingly.

Now, some days later, when I run `npm run dev`, or `prod` or `watch` for that matter, node returns the following (file names adapted):

```
DONE  Compiled successfully in 224711ms

           Asset       Size               Chunks             Chunk Names
 /css/victor.css    0 bytes  /js/bob, /js/ceasar  [emitted]  /js/bob, /js/ceasar
 /css/wiliam.css    0 bytes  /js/bob, /js/ceasar  [emitted]  /js/bob, /js/ceasar
/css/xanthos.css    0 bytes  /js/bob, /js/ceasar  [emitted]  /js/bob, /js/ceasar
   /css/yale.css    0 bytes  /js/bob, /js/ceasar  [emitted]  /js/bob, /js/ceasar
    /css/zac.css    0 bytes  /js/bob, /js/ceasar  [emitted]  /js/bob, /js/ceasar
    /js/alice.js   1.81 MiB            /js/alice  [emitted]  /js/alice
      /js/bob.js   47.2 KiB              /js/bob  [emitted]  /js/bob
   /js/ceasar.js   2.72 MiB           /js/ceasar  [emitted]  /js/ceasar
            0.js   28.5 KiB                    0  [emitted]
            1.js    114 KiB                    1  [emitted]
```

And indeed, the files are in fact empty.

I've checked the webpack.mix.js and also the main scss files and those they include. – And found nothing particularly suspicious.
I've also tried reinstalling all node_modules.

The webpack.mix.js looks like this:

```js
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

 mix.js('resources/js/bob.js', 'public/js')
    .js('resources/js/ceasar.js', 'public/js')
    .js('resources/js/alice.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/kyle/wiliam.scss', 'public/css')
    .sass('resources/sass/kyle/xanthos.scss', 'public/css')
    .sass('resources/sass/victor.scss', 'public/css')
    .sass('resources/sass/yale.scss', 'public/css')
    .sass('resources/sass/zac.scss', 'public/css');

if (mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.version();
}
```

(That's all there is, just in case someone asks.)

I'd like to have my working scss compiler back up and running.
Where does this problem come from? Have I messed something up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is some general and known issues when you have async loaded files/components in your application code.

[This clearly shows upstream issues further down in the open issue](https://github.com/roots/sage/issues/2204)

For you now you could try to remove your dynamic imports, some developers also got it to work if you import an empty .css file in to your javascript file.

Answer (score 0):

I have found some useful guidance in this [issue](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/1914) on the Github page of Laravel Mix.

The idea is to create two separate node tasks for the css and the js files. I have tried it on a fresh install of Laravel (which is using Laravel Mix v4.0.7) and it's working.